# How to display single document from collection on button click with meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates, meteor

I'm trying to retrieve a single random document from the database on a button click. When the page loads, it does get a single document and displays on the webpage; but when I try to click the button to retrieve another random document and display on the webpage it does not work.

The issue is passing the object to the html file. Yes, I am new to Meteor/ template system.

main.html

```
<body>
<ul>
   {{#each resolutions}}
    {{> resolution}}
   {{/each}}
</ul>
</body>

<template name="resolution">
<li>
  <span class="text">{{question}}</span><br>
  <button type="button" name="button" class="change-question">Change Question</button>
<br>
</li>
</template>
```

main.js

```
  Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection('questions');

  Template.resolution.events({
  'click .change-question': function(event, instance){

  var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
  var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
  // choose a random item by skipping N items
  var item = Resolutions.findOne({},{
    skip: random
  });
  var objArray = $.makeArray(item);

  instance.question.set(objArray);
   // window.alert("sometext" + objArray);
   }
   });

  Template.body.helpers({
  resolutions: function() {
    var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
    var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
    // choose a random item by skipping N items
    var item = Resolutions.findOne({},{
      skip: random
    });
    var objArray = $.makeArray(item);
    return objArray;
    }
    });
```

The ERROR message says 'cannot read property set of undefined'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `instance.question` is undefined.  Are you sure it's being set?  Where is `instance` coming from?

Comment: I do not think it's being set. I did try to set it with Template.resolution.onCreated and Template.resolution.helpers, but it didn't get me anywhere. If you know how it works and are able to share, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Well, I guess I am confused as to where `instance` is even coming from.  Usually you would use `this` in a template and set stuff on it.